# I wish to install the 4digits game

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I have downloaded and extracted 4digits-1.1.4. Where do I go from here?
In Ubuntu 19.10, I got it running and of course, I don't remember how. When I updated it was gone. In 20.04 I have not been able to do it again. It's my favorite game. Please help.

Comment: When you tested with a LiveUSB of 20.04 to make sure your important apps were available in the new release, did it appear then?

Comment: I didn't do that, but I can.

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/4digits/1.1.4-1build1 shows it is not yet supported for 20.04 'Focal Fossa'.  If it's essential, you can step back to version [18.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.4/) where it is available, and wait until it is ported to the new release, or [contact the developer directly](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=panyongzhi@gmail.com) to ask why.

Answer (score 0):

The game can be downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fourdigits/files/latest/download) and manually compiled/installed.Also see [HP](http://fourdigits.sourceforge.net/)

**Installation: Linux**

4digits is distributed in [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/4digits) and [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/4digits), so you can install it from [APT](http://apt://4digits).

Python is usually already installed in your computer if your are a using a modern Linux distribution. You can install python-gtk2 and python-glade2 from the software repository of your distribution.
BSD's and Unix's

Install python, python-gtk2 and python-glade2 for your system.